# Does the 90/180 rule apply to an EU citizen in Switzerland?

Tags: switzerland, 90-180-visa-rules, bulgarian-citizens

I'm a Bulgarian national that is living and working in Portugal with Permanent Residence Card and would like to visit Switzerland as my SO is currently living and working there.

Does the 90/180 rule apply?

I've been applying the rule just to be safe, but I've never been stopped at border when I flew in (or flew out) nor when I entered (or exited) with my own vehicle.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Bulgaria is a member state of the European Union.  As a Bulgarian national, you are also a citizen of the union and you enjoy freedom of movement in the Schengen area.

As long as you don't live in Switzerland for more than 3 months *at a time* you are within your rights.

Comment: [Entry to Switzerland and residence for citizens of EU/EFTA countries](https://www.eda.admin.ch/eda/en/fdfa/entry-switzerland-residence/information-entry-switzerland-residence.html): **For a stay over 90 days you will require an authorisation from the migration authority of the canton concerned.**

Comment: This answer desperately needs to cite a source.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the rule you cite has nothing to do to with the 90/180 rule.

Comment: @Kyralessa here's a link to the Schengen Borders Code, which applies the 90/180 rule to "third-country nationals": https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02016R0399-20190611

Comment: This is probably a bit of a shortcut. Switzerland may be in Schengen, but it’s not an EU member state, so the EU freedom of movement provisions do not apply. Switzerland have their own free movement agreement with the EU, which has different rules. So the 90/180 rule may not apply, but there lay be other restrictions (as highlighted by @MarkJohnson). Ahhh the wonderful world of intersecting transnational agreements...

Comment: This is a naive interpretation of "freedom of movement" (admittedly most people miss the nuances). Even if you're an European citizen and moving to another EU country there are limits.  [See here for example](https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/european_government/european_union/freedom_of_movement_in_the_eu.html#leb0a3). #4 ("You have money to support yourself and health insurance (for you and your family) without state assistance") would have to be shown which may or may not be a challenge.

Comment: @phoog No, it doesn't. It implements **Article 8 (1) Freedom of Movement** for Switzerland (which you failed to meantion). [DIRECTIVE 2004/58/EC - Article 8 - Administrative formalities for Union citizens](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32004L0038R%2801%29#d1e716-): **1. Without prejudice to Article 5(5), for periods of residence longer than three months, the host Member State may require Union citizens to register with the relevant authorities.**

Comment: @jcaron The **90/180 days rule** does not apply for EU-Citizens, Swiss etc. **Article 8 (1) Freedom of Movement**, however, does apply for the same.

Comment: @Voo Your named conditions are based on **Article 7 Freedom of Movement** [DIRECTIVE 2004/58/EC - Article 7 - Right of residence for more than three months](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32004L0038R%2801%29#d1e633-)

Comment: @Mark Thanks, I was on my phone and that one was the first site I found. Nice to have the official reference.

Comment: @jcaron that is correct.  I answered the question as asked.  There are other considerations aside from the 90/180 rule, but the asker has neither asked about them nor explained what is meant by "I've been applying the rule."  I did not have time to go into a discussion of the details, but I have added a little more information.

Comment: @Voo yes there are limits, but the 90/180 rule is not relevant.  I don't know what interpretation you find naive as I did not offer an interpretation of "freedom of movement."  Had the question sought to elicit more detail I might have added it, or I might have decided not to answer.  The requirement you cite, I would add, doors not apply to visits of less than three months' duration, and we don't know that OP is seeking to remain for longer than three months at a time.  Regardless, anyone and everyone is welcome to add a more detailed answer.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm not sure what you mean by "no, it doesn't"; are you agreeing or disagreeing?  The free movement right of residence, whether for less or more than three months, is entirely distinct from the 90/180 rule.  As for practical advice for The OP, it depends rather on the duration (and possibly frequency) of the anticipated periods of presence in Switzerland.  These are not mentioned in the question.

Comment: (+1) @jcaron Switzerland is in fact bound by the EU freedom of movement under its bilateral agreements with the EU. Importantly, directive 2004/38/EC is where that freedom of movement is defined. Being able to require some form of registration and check against the conditions for long term stay is a very minor restriction and how this works everywhere in the EU. To the extent that Switzerland would be different, it would be because this directive does *not* apply. It makes absolutely no sense to invoke it as evidence that there are special restrictions or to object to phoog's answer.

Comment: @Voo “You enjoy freedom of movement” isn't an interpretation at all, how can it be a naive one? That the 90/180 rule doesn't apply is also a simple fact. Stating both seem useful, given the level of confusion exhibited in the question and in the comments. If you peruse phoog's other answers, you will see s/he intimately familiar with EU freedom of movement law and there is absolutely nothing in the references quoted since that are inconsistent with this answer (in either its original or expanded version).

Comment: @jcaron The bilateral agreement meationed is the [Agreement on the Free Movement of Persons (AFMP)](https://www.sem.admin.ch/sem/en/home/themen/fza_schweiz-eu-efta.html), signed on the 21 June 1999.

Comment: As an EU citizen residing in Switzerland I can confirm EU citizens need a residence permit to stay in Switzerland beyond 90 days per 180-day period. However, it only involves fulfilling EU requirements for residence (showing employment/studies etc.) and paying the fee (CHF 66 each year for me). It's done at the municipal registration office who forwards it to the cantonal migration board, with the actual permit issued by the former. Finally, whether an EU citizen has respected the 90/180 rule is **not** something border officials will be bothered about (nor are their entries/exits registered)

Comment: @Crazydre I believe you misunderstand.  There is no "90 days per 180-day period" for EU citizens.  For example, if an EU citizen stays for 60 days, leaves for two weeks, and returns, the second visit is not limited to 30 days (as it would be for a third-country national).

Comment: @phoog Hrm, asked around today and different municipalities seem to interpret it differently. You might be right.